# Unable to Deploy field

Tags: deployment, custom-field, package, package.xml

I Created a field `Web_Security_Scove` in an environment and i am trying to deploy it in to another environment.

My Retrieve package:

[image]

My Package.xml:

[image]

I am getting the following error after deployment:
[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: Since you've mentioned package.xml, are you using the Salesforce Migration Tool (i.e. ANT) to do your deployment? If so, are you sure that your target in build.xml is being pointed to the package.xml file that you've retrieved?

Comment: No I am using workbench.Here  i got extract in zipped folder.One folder with name Object and attched fist xml and other is package.xml

Answer (score 0):

Probably is not the case, but I cannot see the "**__c**" suffix in the CustomObject file, **fullName** node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fields>
        <fullName>Web_Security_Scove__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Web_Security_Scove</label>
        <length>211</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

In the other hand if the CustomField package.xml doesn't work (and I wonder why Lead is written without capital L), try using a CustomObject package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <type>CustomObject</type>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```